# Como checar se uma tabela do banco de dados mysql já existe com o codeigniter4?

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, codeigniter, formulário

Como verificar se já exista uma determinada tabela  banco de dados MySQL com o  codeigniter 4, e se não existir, criar essa tabela ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer uma consulta para ver se a tabela existe realmente, exemplo:

```
if ($this->db->table_exists($table) )
{
  // table exists some code run query
}
else
{
  // table does not exist
}
```

E para criar uma tabela você pode utilizar esse trecho(ele já faz uma validação para ver se existe ou não a tabela em questão).

```
$this->dbforge->create_table('table_name', TRUE);
```